# Fetch API cookies not accessible?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, passport.js, fetch

I have a React app that makes a REST POST request to an express backend thats running passportjs for authentication. I'm trying to use the Fetch API to send the POST request, but when I do I dont know how to access the cookie being sent back from the server. I see the response headers shows the cookie i want in the devtools and also when I use regular html  it works and the cookie is sent automatically and persisted. My problem is I cant persist the cookie when using the Fetch API, since i dont know how to access it after its received.

```
  login () {
    const data = {
      username: this.state.username,
      password: this.state.password
    }

    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        credentials: 'include' // tried this too.
        // credentials: 'same-origin'
      }
    }

    fetch('/login', options)
      .then(res => {
        console.log('res', res)
        // cookies.set('connect.sid', document.cookie['connect.sid'])
        console.log(document.cookie['connect.sid'])// undefined
        console.log(res.headers) // empty
        console.log(document.cookies) // undefined
        // cookies.set('connect.sid', res.headers) // need to set this but where is the cookie from server?
      })
      .then(this.clearInputFields.bind(this))
  }
```

and here are the response headers im currently getting with FETCH API:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-powered-by: Express
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
content-length: 14
etag: W/"e-Xft1SGvF5rPEfqfROtKDA2epBao"
set-cookie: connect.sid=s%3ACRnk3A0b0o5T8VSQTVpvTUgW54lO38IJ.skdIbmipmb1CGn6oEQ5KzdS2zGdNiZQrFDwU5cTuy7A; Path=/
date: Tue, 05 Jun 2018 00:32:15 GMT
connection: close
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

connect.sid is what I want to set. I've seen other articles on this but they dont seem to address my particular issue. Any guidance?

EDIT:

```
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
  credentials: 'include', // credentials moved to here fixed the issue
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}

fetch('/login', options)
  .then(this.clearInputFields.bind(this))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the `credentials` in the `header` object when it is not a header.

Also, `cookies` is not a property of `document`, rather it is `document.cookie`.

Comment: That worked, I also removed the part where I tried to set cookies manually. After putting the credentials in the correct place they were automatically set. Thanks :)